# How to use existing Spring Cloud Data Flow Starter/Sample Applications with Source bean?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Working on a new CDF Source application I noticed that `@EnableBinding` is deprecated so I implemented a `MessageSource` with a `Supplier` bean

```
    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<LogRecord>>> getLogs() {
```

For testing I created a stream between my Source and the File Sink. Both services came-up just fine, but they refused to communicate. I could see the Source write to the stream, and the Sink listening but they acted like they were not on the same channel.

Finally I modified the code to use `@EnableBinding` and `@PollableSource` and everything worked as it should.

I can't find anything in the documentation about this, what have I missed?

Thanks in advance.

--- Update ---

Source:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class KinesisSource {
    @Autowired
    KinesisMessageSource kinesisMessageSource;
    public KinesisSource(){
    }

    @Bean
    public Supplier<Flux<Message<LogRecord>>> getLogs() {
        return () -> IntegrationReactiveUtils.messageSourceToFlux(kinesisMessageSource);
    }
}
```

Source config:

```
spring.cloud.function.definition=getLogs
spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.getLogs-out-0=output
```

Sink is the [provided File Sink Starter](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/blob/main/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-file/README.adoc).

Comment: Check your `supplier` `application.properties` has the correct output binding `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.getLogs-out-0=output` as noted by @sobychacko.

Answer (score 1):

You can find various example of writing suppliers using the functional model here: https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/tree/main/functions/supplier

When using the functional model, going by your example, your default binding becomes `getLogs-out-0`. Is that the binding you used for your producer?

If you want a reactive style supplier to poll on a schedule, see this specific example: https://github.com/spring-cloud/stream-applications/blob/main/functions/supplier/jdbc-supplier/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/fn/supplier/jdbc/JdbcSupplierConfiguration.java#L66

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My issue is getting the binding name correct so the Starters written annotation-style will work unchanged.

Comment: See the comment above given by fiidim. I think that is what you need.

Comment: `spring.cloud.stream.function.bindings.getLogs-out-0=output` hasn't changed the behavior- the annotation sink isn't receiving anything from the function source even though the  log shows the source writing to the channel.

Comment: Could you show your source and sink with the configuration?

Comment: I've updated the original post. Thanks for your help.